# How to display the installed dotnet new template version numbers

Tags: templates, .net-core

I have installed a series of dotnet templates for use with

```
dotnet new
```

by using cli options such as

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0
```

or

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::*
```

as described here [Available-templates-for-dotnet-new](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-templates-for-dotnet-new)

How do I list what versions of templates I have installed?
the output of

```
dotnet new
```

doesn't display the current version of the template

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║        Templates                                                 Short Name       Language          Tags         ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ║
║ Console Application                                       console          [C#], F#, VB      Common/Console      ║
║ Class library                                             classlib         [C#], F#, VB      Common/Library      ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: I do >dotnet new -u 
this lists all templates and versions along with the right name to uinstall the template if you want to.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two ways to get template version.

**First**, you can use the documented [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates#get-a-list-of-installed-templates)

```
dotnet new -u
```

[image]

**Second**, you can use the following command:

```
dotnet new --debug:showconfig
```

which will show you all installed templates with their version number.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[update - note that this post is now over 2 years old, and the tooling appears to have gotten much better]
The best I seem to come up with is to look in

`C:\Users\BozoJoe\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.104\packages`

which has the nupkgs with the version numbers in the file names (as well as the nupkg zips)

Comment: There is a dotnet tool I created called TemplateVersions.Tool which lists all versions found in `C:\Users\BozoJoe\.templateengine\dotnetcli\` and can even list all packages across all versions. I built it specifically to solve the problem of not being able to see installed template versions.